# Как найти самое часто используемое слово в тексте?

Tags: c#

Как найти самое часто используемое слово в тексте на C#? Какие могут быть подходы в решении задачи?

Comment: словарь, где слово - ключ, количество его использований - значение

Answer (score 0):

```
var word_count = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach(var word in [массив/List/что-либо еще со словами])
   if(word_count.ContainsKey(word))
      word_count[word]++;
   else
      word_count.Add(word, 1);

string most_frequent_word = word_count.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Value > y.Value ? x : y).Value;
```

Comment: почему бы не просто `var most_frequent_word = word_count.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Value).First().Key;`?

Comment: или `[массив/List/что-либо еще со словами].GroupBy(x=>x).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count()).First().Key` - вся логика одной строкой.