# Сколько раз встречается слово в тексте

Tags: c#

Юзер вводит большой текст. Требуется создать частотный словарь. это словарь в котором ключ уникальное слово из текста, а значение числовое. Сколько раз в тексте встречается данное слово?

```
Машина машина собака машина собака свинья 
Машина  3 
собака  2
свинья  1
```

Что я пробовал:
Я инициализировал словарь, и разделил введенный юзером текст с помощью Split.
Затем, я проверяю с помощью счетчика, одинакового ли нынешнее слово со следующим. Если одинаково, добавляю в копилку.
Ошибка: Индекс вне границ

```
var Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Console.WriteLine("Вводи большой текст");
string text = Console.ReadLine();
string[] newText = text.Split(' ');

int counterRepeat = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < newText.Length; i++)
{
    if (newText[i] == newText[i + 1])
    {
        counterRepeat++;
    }
}
```

Comment: ну и очевидно же! если ``newText[i]`` будет последний элемента, то что должно быть в ``newText[i + 1]``? Примитивной отладке уже совсем не учат? Кстати, этот код считает совсем не то, что нужно.

Comment: Начните с этого `Требуется создать частотный словарь. это словарь в котором ключ уникальное слово из текста, а значение числовое.`

Comment: Связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1135932/179763

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/840434/220553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует лучше пройтись по массиву слов и сохранять каждый новый ключ в словарь с сопоставленным числом равным единице, а если в словаре уже есть такой ключ, значит нужно прибавить к значению, лежащему под этим ключом единицу, кстати, словарь должен быть типа строка - число, а не строка - строка.

Вот реализация:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Counter
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        Console.Write("Input your text: ");
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] words = text.Split(' ');
        
// Пробегаемся по полученную после разделения текста массиву слов и складываем в словарь
        foreach(var word in words) {
            if (!counts.ContainsKey(word.ToLower())) counts.Add(word.ToLower(), 1);
            else counts[word] += 1;
        }
        
// Пробегаемся по словарю и выводим все элементы
        foreach(var pair in counts) {
            Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + ": " + pair.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо! единственное что осталось непонятным, это восклицательный знак перед counts, что он значит в данном коде?

Comment: @yeah, это оператор "отрицание", то есть всё описанное условие становится "не". В данном случае читается условие так "если НЕ содержится в словаре ключа являющегося словом из массива, то добавить его и к нему значение 1"

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант сделать то, что вам нужно, - это LINQ:

```
var text = "Машина машина собака машина собака свинья";

var dictionary = text.Split()
    .GroupBy(word => word) // группируем одинаковые слова
    .ToDictionary(group => group, group => group.Count()); // превращаем группы в словарь
```